# Save peer dependencies in npm with a command

Tags: npm, npm-install

Is there a way to achieve that using npm  ? Currently I do this manually, would be nice to use similar approach as with npm install --save

I found some old discussion and commits but it seems it didn't make it:

https://github.com/npm/npm/pull/3994

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you can't. Just install it as a regular dependency (production or otherwise, just like the package requiring the peer dependency is installed as).

Even if you manually add the entry to `peerDependencies` an `npm audit` is going to fail to recognize the package and tell you to install it.

This kind of stinks, I'm a big fan of the separation of concerns, and keeping a list of modules that only exist so they can be absorbed by other modules is crummy.

But, it is what it is and so long as you leverage the npm commands afforded to you, I guess it's manageable.

Comment: yeah, it's not hurting me that much since the list of peer dependencies is not changing that often. I was more inclined to update their versions rigorously but instead i went with the npm tag so unless my developer  wants to explicitly set a version we use the latest snapshot produced from development branch. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Since 'I don't know what npm version' you can use `npm i --save-peer package_name` command. Works on npm 8.1.0