# installing dependencies in a angular library

Tags: angular, ngrx-store

I have created angular application in 10 which is of workspace where i have a library and a application

I understand we can install dependencies in the application with the command -

```
 npm install @ngrx/store
```

Now suppose if i have to install the dependencies in the library how should i do it.?for example what i need to do get the package.json to be updated as given below.

```
{
  name: '@customerReport',
  version: '0.0.1',
  peerDeependencies : {
   @angular/common : '^10.1.6',
   @angular/core : '^10.1.6',
   @ngrx/store' : '^10.1.2'
}
}
```

Most of the samples are related to application but not to library.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Save peer dependencies in npm with a command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54218354/save-peer-dependencies-in-npm-with-a-command)

Comment: i tried understanding the content in the above url. From what i see that is no command available to install a dependency in the library. as a alternative we can copy and past the required dependencies as peer dependencies. Further as per the article https://indepth.dev/posts/1187/npm-peer-dependencies, when it is keep it as peer dependencies, we dont need to have a sperate node_modules

Comment: Library has a package.json, doesnt it? In the terminal, just navigate to your libraryroot directory and run your npm install there? You could probably just copy paste the dependencies to the package.json as well.

Comment: did you mean to install node_modules in the library. No.